# Value of <HANDLE> construct can be "0"; test with defined() at perltestscript.pl line 16

Tags: regex, perl

My code looks like this. Does anyone know how I can test this error or why I am getting this? The problem is in line 16 which is the bracket above `chomp $stringtoFind`: in my code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $syslogFile = 'syslog';
open (my $syslogInfo, '<', $syslogFile) or die "Could not open $syslogFile";

my $keywordFile = 'keyword';
open (my $keywordInfo, '<', $keywordFile) or die "Could not open $keywordFile";


while (my $line = <$syslogInfo>)
{
    if(my $stringtoFind =~ <$keywordInfo>)
    {   
        chomp $stringtoFind;
        #print "$line\n";
        $stringtoFind =~ ( ^/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\s[a-zA-Z]*\s($stringtoFind).*/s);
        open(outputFile, ">>output");
        flock(outputFile, 2);
        print outputFile "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Also another question. I don't know why but my code is outputting something very different that what I intended to find.

In the syslog file I have:

```
Dec 27 21:17:52 osboxes rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.12.0" x-pid="695" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 27 21:18:05 osboxes anacron[634]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Dec 27 21:18:05 osboxes anacron[634]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    lease time 1800
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    domain name 'localdomain'
```

To which I only intended to output anything that contains NetworkManager in my keyword but instead outputs the ones that does not contain NetworkManager and it confuses me to why that is. Any help would be appreciated as of the current state as I am kinda new to Perl, I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to anchor a regular expression to the start of the line is to have `^` as the first character of the expression (that is after the first `/`).

`$stringtoFind =~ ( /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\s[a-zA-Z]*\s($stringtoFind).*/s);`

This is also an error `if(my $stringtoFind =~<$keywordInfo>)`. `=~` is the pattern match operator. So this line does not make any sense, as it matches a string inside a newly created variable, and `<>` is reading line(s) from a filehandle, and should not be used like this.

`if (defined(my $stringtoFind = <$keywordInfo>))`

and the script compiles for me.

The error you are getting is the test from the `<$keywordInfo>`. A line from a file can be `0`, which evaluates to `false` in perl. You should therefore test with `defined` when checking for `eof`.

Your script will match every line of the syslog-file with the matching line in keyword-file, as you read one line from the keyword-file for every line in the syslog-file. So line 3 of syslog will be match with line 3 of keyword. If keyword-file has fewer lines, the line will not be matched at all. This is probably not what you want. You are better off reading all the lines in the keyword-file into an array before you start your loop, and then iterate over them for each line in the syslog-file. If you use something like [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) you can even create a single regular expression to match the lines with, so you don't need to iterate.

Comment: So instead of doing  my $line and $stringtoFind, I must do @line and @stringtoFind? Also just question is the .*/s at the end does indeed match every line which is something I do not want and I'm trying to find an equivalent of this python code "re.search(r'\:\s[^^]+\S', string, re.I|re.M)" in perl. so the question is, is there a ^^ equivalent in perl as I cannot seem to find anything about it in the books?

Comment: No. That will not solve it. You need to read the files separate, and not read keyword-file inside the line of syslog-file.

The question about the regular expression should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: You cannot read the empty string from a file. If there are no characters remaining then `<>` returns `undef

Comment: Sorry, kinda new to stackoverflow, just accepted the answer just now and thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find an equivalent in perl of this python code:
>
> ```
> re.search(r'\:\s[^^]+\S', string, re.I|re.M)
> ```

Then it might be enlightening to understand what the python code does:

```
import re

test_strs = [
    ": abc^ X",
    "\: abc^ X",
]

for test_str in test_strs:
    if re.match(r'\:\s[^^]+\S', test_str):
        print(test_str)

--output:--
: abc^ X
```

Things to note:

1. In regexes, the `:` is not a special character so it does not need to be escaped, therefore the `\:` in the regex is equivalent to just `:`.
2. The case insensitive search, `re.I`, has no effect because the regex does not specify any upper or lower case letters.
3. The multiline flag, `re.M`, has no effect because the regex does not try to use `^` or `$` to match the beginning or end of a string.

As a result, the regex can be reduced to this:

```
re.search(r':\s[^^]+\S', string)
```

And that regex is the same in perl:

```
string =~ /:\s[^^]+\S/
```

If you wanted to add the flags that have no effect, you could write:

```
string =~ /:\s[^^]+\S/im
```

> so the question is, is there a ^^ equivalent in perl as I cannot seem
>   to find anything about it in the books?

The following portion of the regex:

```
[^^]+
```

reads like this:

```
[  ]  => This is known as a 'character class', and it means: match
         a single character if it is one of the characters listed 
         inside the brackets

[^ ]  => A 'negated character class'.  Match a single character if it 
         is not one of the characters listed inside the brackets

[^^]  => What are the characters inside  the 'negated character
         class' [^  ]?  That's simply (the second) ^, so the
         whole thing means: match any single character that 
         is not a ^.

[^^]+  => Match a single character that is not a ^, one or more times
```

Because the `^` character does not appear in your logfile, that part of the regex effectively means: match any character, one or more times.